# Check if user is logged in?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to insert new column to Users list in WP admin area which shows "Yes" or "No" if user is currently logged in or not.

**Makes new column:**

```
function users_events_column( $cols ) {

  //Column key + show icon as column heading
  $cols['logged_in'] = '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>';

  return $cols;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'users_events_column' );
```

**Logic and content for each user in column:**

```
function user_events_column_value( $column_name ) {

  if( $column_name == 'logged_in' ) {

    if(     /*Somehow check if user is logged in*/     ) {

       _e( 'Yes', 'kk' );

    }
    else {

       _e( 'No', 'kk' );

    }
  }
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'user_events_column_value', 10, 3 );
```

**How to check if user in list is logged in?**

---

**Update:**

I tried this but it's not working..

```
function user_log_column_value( $column_name ) {
  if( $column_name == 'logged_in' ) {

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

       _e( 'Yes', 'kk' );

    }
    else {

       _e( 'No', 'kk' );

    }
  }
    }
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'user_log_column_value', 10, 3 );
```

Column  gets created successfully but there's no content - no "No" or "Yes"

Comment: Why doesn't it work for you? It's a standard WP function.

Comment: You don't need to touch a custom column for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a [built-in function that does this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in):

```
is_user_logged_in();
```

> Returns `true` if user is logged in, `false` if not logged in.